# Rollover log files which limits number of files of each day

Tags: java, scala, logging, log4j, logback

I'm configuring logging behavior using `logback`, the [doc](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) shows some usage including :

1. `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`: rolling log files by time (daily, monthly...)
2. `FixedWindowRollingPolicy`: limits number of files created.

What I want to do is: generate log files each day, also **limit the number of files** generated at a given day, for example, the maximum number of log files should be 10, if more files coming, older ones should be deleted, total number of files is FIXED at 10. So it's kinda mixed behavior of 1 and 2. Unfortunately, there's no solution to combine the two policies according to doc.

Is there any way or workaround? Thanks.

(Actually, I'm working with Scala, but I guess that's same as Java regarding to this question)